# Class member declared only to be passed to other class

Tags: design-patterns, c++, object-oriented-design, factory

Given three classes:

```
class A {
    B* b_;
    A(B* b){
        b_ = b;
    }

    void doThings() {
        C* c = new C(b_);
        ...
        // Use c
    }
}

class B {}

class C {
    B* b_;
    C(B* b) {
        b_ = b;
        ...
    }
}
```

The reference to `B` in class `A` is useful only for passing it to `C` when needed, because `A` and `C` **cannot** create instance of `B`.

I am wondering if I could avoid having the reference in `A` using some design pattern: I do **not** think making `B` a singleton is a good solution and I think that a Factory could be better, but maybe is an over complication.

Is the unused reference a real problem? Does a factory solve my problem?

Comment: It's hard to answer without more details of the problem. On it's face, however, just having the pointer to B is not problem as long as there's a reasonable guarantee about the lifetime of B

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an instance of `C` should be an argument to the `doThings` method. `C` is not a class-wide dependency, and `_b` only serves as a dependency to `C`, therefore something else should create `C` and pass it to `doThings`.

---

You'll have to forgive me, I haven't written c++ since... college? Pointer/reference syntax might be a tad off.

---

```cpp
class A {
    A() { }

    void doThings(C* c) {
        // Use c
    }
};

class B { };

class C {
    B* _b;

    C(B* b) {
        _b = b;
    }
};
```

Something has to coordinate between `A`, `B` and `C`:

```cpp
class X {
    void doStuff() {
        B b;
        C c(&b);
        A a;

        a.doThings(&c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pass c into the constructor for A

```
class A {
    C* c_;
    A(C* c){
        c_ = c;
    }

    void doThings() {
        ...
        // Use c_
    }
}

class C {
    B* b_;
    C(B* b) {
        b_ = b;
        ...
    }
}
```